# EasyUI treegrid customize header text

Tags: css, jquery-easyui

I am trying to center a header text in the above control:

```
 var td = $(elem).treegrid('getPanel').find('div.datagrid-header td[field="alarms"]');
        td.css('text-align', 'center');
        td.css('height', '40');
```

The height gets changed to 40, but the text is not aligning.What might the problem be?

Thanks

Comment: _horizontal_ center should work, or you meant _vertical_ center?

Comment: No, I want to center the text

Comment: You can set the halign='center' for that column.

Comment: Does not work. I think it's something in the product.